# Adding a camera to my urdf

Tags: urdf, ros-indigo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to add a camera to the end of an arm using xacros. The camera link URDF is:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:macro name="camera" params="parent">
    <link name="camera">
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://sensors_and_actuators/meshes/camara.stl" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
   
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://sensors_and_actuators/meshes/camara.stl" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
   
      <inertial>
        <mass value="1e-5" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="sensor_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="camera"/>
        <origin rpy="0 1.5620 0" xyz="0.0475 0.0 0.0"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="camera">
      <sensor type="camera" name="camera_sensor">
        <parent link="camera"/>
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <format>R8G8B8</format>
            <width>800</width>
            <height>800</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.01</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
        </camera>

        <plugin name="${name}_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <cameraName>arm_sensors/camera</cameraName>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera</frameName>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>

  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

When I run the launch file it reports an error saying that the parent param is missing:

```
samper@samper:~$ roslaunch cern_tim_arm_simulator arm_tim_simulator.launch spawn_arm:=true robotic_arm:=schunk_lwa4p world:=tunnel spawn_collimator:=true camera_on_arm:=true
... logging to /home/samper/.ros/log/2c17a290-4b39-11e5-b79f-605718079cbb/roslaunch-samper-16690.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 696, in main
    eval_self_contained(doc)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 626, in eval_self_contained
    eval_all(doc.documentElement, macros, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 552, in eval_all
    (",".join(params), str(node.tagName)))
xacro.XacroException: Parameters [parent] were not set for macro camera
while processing /home/samper/ROS_Workspaces/ROS_Cern/src/ros_cern/tim_gazebo/load_world.launch:
while processing /home/samper/ROS_Workspaces/ROS_Cern/src/ros_cern/robotic_arm/launch/schunk_lwa4p_and_tim.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/samper/ROS_Workspaces/ROS_Cern/src/ros_cern/robotic_arm/arm_description/robots/schunk_lwa4p/schunk_lwa4p_arm_and_tim_camera.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find robotic_arm)/arm_description/robots/schunk_lwa4p/schunk_lwa4p_arm_and_tim_camera.urdf.xacro'" if="$(arg camera_on_arm)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me any clue.
Thank you in advance.

JLuis Samper

PS: it only works if i delete the  tag and its content

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216496/adding-a-camera-to-my-urdf/) by [Samper-Esc](https://answers.ros.org/users/19841/samper-esc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2015-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case that someone has this problem, i just solved it changing the inertial values. Gazebo has a problem when has to work with small values in the inertial block. Additionally I just omitted the parent tag, it is taken from the joint.

If you need to orientate the position of the optical focus you can do it by the pose property tag of the gazebo plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.1415926535897931" />

  <xacro:macro name="camera_link" params="parent">

    
    <link name="camera_link">
     
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://sensors_and_actuators/meshes/camara.stl" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>

        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://sensors_and_actuators/meshes/camara.stl" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="grey">
            <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0"/>
        </material>
      </visual>


      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.001" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001" />
      </inertial>

    </link>
    


    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.047 0.0 0.0"/>
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    </joint>

  
    
    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
      <sensor type="camera" name="camera_camera_sensor">
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <camera>
          <pose>0.035 0 0.078 0 ${-M_PI/2} 0</pose>
          <horizontal_fov>${85 * M_PI/180.0}</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <format>R8G8B8</format>
            <width>1020</width>
            <height>1020</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.01</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
        </camera>

        <plugin name="camera_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>arm_sensor/camera</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
          <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
          <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Samper-Esc](https://answers.ros.org/users/19841/samper-esc/) with karma: 50 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-21**:
Can you please accept your own answer? That way it is clear from the question listing that it has been answered.

**Comment by [Samper-Esc](https://answers.ros.org/users/19841/samper-esc/) on 2016-04-21**:
I tried but it says that i need more than 10 points

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-21**:
Ah, right. Just accepted it for you.

**Comment by [Samper-Esc](https://answers.ros.org/users/19841/samper-esc/) on 2016-04-21**:
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually you're using a fairly common name. It is likely that the macro name "camera" is similar to a an already defined xacro macro. Try renaming the xacro:macro to something a little more unique such as "my_camera_link". I had this problem with a xacro macro named "sphere". Changing the macro name solved the issue and xacro confusion.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-12-12**:
UNBELIEVABLE!!!
Thank you.